# How to compile and run C# project from terminal (Mac OS)

Tags: c#, mongodb, terminal, mono, visual-studio-mac

I want to compile and run C# project on Mac OS server. There's no GUI to use, so I need to compile and run it from terminal.

I copied the directory of my C# project from my local to the server.
(My C# project was created by visual studio for mac.)

On the server, I have already installed `mono`. I can compile and run the basic C# code 'hello world!' by `mcs Program.cs` and `mono Program.exe` but I cannot compile and run my project.

my `Program.cs` code is like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
namespace testMongo
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("user");

            //do something
       }

    }
        public class Entity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        public int user_id { get; set; }

        public double[] feature { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but when I try to run `mcs Program.cs` I got this error

```
Program.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(54,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ObjectId' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

It seems that the compiler cannot find MongoDB and I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I can run my project with msbuild

I use `msbuild projectname.sln /p:Configuration=Debug` then I got `projectname.exe` file and run it with `mono projectname.exe`

Comment: You need to pass the assembly references to mcs. So something like `mcs Program.cs /reference:path/to/MongoDb.dll`. You will need to identify which assemblies you need to reference. Alternatively you could just create a .csproj file, add the references or NuGet package there, and use msbuild to compile your code.

Comment: Thank you @MattWard I use `mcs Program.cs /reference:path/to/MongoDb.dll` for all reference and it can be compiled. I got the Program.exe file but when I ran it with `mono Program.exe` I got this error `Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'` How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to reference all .dlls that your program uses. Just MongoDb.dll is not enough. If you look at your .csproj you should see which assemblies are being referenced. I still think using msbuild would be easier than trying to create the mcs command line by hand.

Comment: You could look at the msbuild output when compiling your project with Visual Studio for Mac and re-use the csc command line. Or just use msbuild on the server. Or just build it locally and then copy the binaries to the server.

Comment: @MattWard Thank you very much! I tried to use msbuild instead of mcs command and it works!